# Tensorflow takes a lot of time to restore a ckpt model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

It takes a lot of time to restore a ckpt model in tensorflow. I am currently using tensorflow-gpu 1.0.0.rc0. My model is about 500M, and it takes about 1 minutes to restore the model. However, it takes only a few seconds when i using tensorflow-gpu 0.11.0 to restore the same model. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm not using the product you ask about, so I'm not going to VTC, but I cannot imagine you will get *any* answer with that little information. You should add more information (for example, how do you restore? Is it a command line? does it have switches or options? If so, which do you use each time?) if you want to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your 1.0.0rc0 installation (why not update to 1.0 proper?) is using the pure python protobuf implementation that you get via pip, whereas the 0.11 installation is using the improved binary distribution from google.

Install the optimized version of protobuf as detailed on https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup#protobuf_library_related_issues 
but you might want to swap 3.1.0 for 3.2.0 in the URLs to get the newer version (I had the issue that the 3.2 "update" came through pip and replaced the optimized 3.1), so instead of

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.1.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

use

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.2.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

or similar depending on your platform and python version.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I tried to compile protobuf locally and it worked.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem again. I am pretty sure that i am using the optimized version of protobuf. Any idea ? is there something else also related to this ？ thanks a lot